# Sybase subquery in from clause cannot have where when called from linkedserver in sql server?

Tags: sql, sybase

The following sql works in sql server via "SAP ASE OLE DB Provider".

```
select * from openquery(Sybase,'
  select * from (
    select * from X
  ) x
')
```

However, the following doesn't work. It sounds like a hideous bug.

```
select * from openquery(Sybase,'
    select * from (
      select * from X 
      where not exists (select * from Y where Y.c = X.c) -- c is not key in both tables
    ) x
')
```

Is it a way to rewrite the subquery to make it work? (it has to be in the subquery). Or is there a problem on the Sybase linked server driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one (if c is integer and cannot be -1)

```
select
    *
from
    (   select
            X.*
        from
            X
            left join ( select distinct
                            c
                        from
                            Y) as y on X.c = y.c
            join (  select
                        -1 as c) as z on coalesce(y.c, -1) = z.c
    ) x
```

Comment: No, it failed because there is a "where" in the subquery.

Comment: so move it outside the query `select * from (
  select X.*, y.c as yc from X left join (select distinct c from Y) as y on X.c = y.c
) x  where yc is null`

Comment: No, I cannot change the outer query. I can only provide the subquery and it will be wrapped in some other outer query code.

Comment: ok, try this (if `c` is integer and cannot be -1) `select * from ( select X.* from X left join (select distinct c from Y) as y on X.c = y.c join (select -1 as c) as z on coalesce(y.c, -1) = z.c) x`

Comment: Yes, joining dummy table works. Hopefully, its performance is not too bad.